# IntelliSense is enabled but not working in SQL Server 2016 with Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql-server-2016, intellisense

I have installed SQL server 2016 whose details are as in below screenshot:

[image: SQL Server 2016 > About]

My queries are pointing to Azure SQL DB.

Below are the screenshot of some other settings that I have found over the internet and applied:

[image: Tools > Options > Text Editor > Transaction SQL > General]

[image: Tools > Options > Text Editor > Transaction SQL > IntelliSense]

I have also tried by refreshing the local cache and reconnecting to the database.

Please share your expert opinion here and help me to make this work.

Comment: Maybe Microsoft Docs about [Troubleshooting intellisense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/troubleshooting-intellisense?view=sql-server-2017) can help.

Comment: Or [this one](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/) (it's targeted at 2012 but much of it is exactly the same in 2016). Also I highly recommend a newer, supported version of SSMS... [17.9.1 or the 18 preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms). **Especially** when dealing with Azure.

Comment: Both, thank you for the help but troubleshooting I have tried and it is not working. Started downloading the 17.9.1 version of SQL server to check if it is working fine with it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I tried by installing the SQL server 2017 but it's still not working.

Comment: Try [this post for working with Azure SQL DB](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2018/04/12/lesson-learned-40-could-it-be-possible-to-use-intellisense-with-an-azure-active-directory-user-in-sql-server-management-studio/).

Answer (score 1):

The setting that made the biggest difference for me was the "Maximum script size", which had to be set to "Unlimited".

[image: SSMS IntelliSense Settings]